# How to manipulate values to use as parameters

Tags: c#, filter

Hi I have a select and a text type input. These controls are used to filter list in a datagrid. The select control has the following options: LastName, MiddleName, FirstName, Gender, City and StudentID. Then I was given this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE ( LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%' OR @LastName = '' )
AND ( MiddleName LIKE '%' + @MiddleName + '%' OR @MiddleName = '' )
AND ( FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' OR @FirstName = '' )
AND ( Gender LIKE '%' + @Gender + '%' OR @Gender = '' )
AND ( City LIKE '%' + @City + '%' OR @City = '' )
AND ( StudentID LIKE '%' + @StudentID + '%' OR @StudentID = '' )
```

So for example, the user selects First Name then typed in "James". That could be read as "Give me the list of students whose First Name is 'James'." In my controller, the only way I thought is using If..Else If or Switch condition. It was like this:

```
string lastName = String.Empty;
string middleName = String.Empty;
and so on..

if(dropdown == "Lastname")
{
lastName = textbox_value;
}
else if(dropdown == "Middlename")
{
middleName = textbox_value;
}
and so on..
```

Then I have method which will pass the values as parameters to my sql query.

```
resultList = GetRecord(lastName, middleName, firstName, gender, city, studentID);
```

My question now is, what is the better way, the cleanest and simplest, than using If..Else and Switch?

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide it somewhere , either in your controller or you can delegate this to another class but delegating it to another helper class will takeout the responsibility. so i would say , you may think of below design

```
 public class ParameterSelector
{


    private Dictionary<string,Action> _dictActionMap = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    public ParameterSelector()
    {
        PopulateDictionaryWithActions();
    }

    private void PopulateDictionaryWithActions()
    {
        _dictActionMap.Add("LastName", () => lastName = txtBox_Value);
        _dictActionMap.Add("MiddleName", () => middleName = txtBox_Value);
    }
 }
```

**and usage**

```
main()
{
  if(_dictActionMap.ContainsKey(dropdown))
      _dictActionMap[_dictActionMap]();
}
```

see to avoid ifs and switches , i used dictionary with relevant actions, this approach has its own drawback for example , we have unnessary actions defined to handle the part of switch / ifs , its give a feeling that we have get rid of ifs/switch but have tradeoffs with  memory requirement so never complicate things which can be handle with simplicity.

so i would say using of Ifs/ Switch has nothing wrong in your case.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: :) , if i saw your comment while typing and before rushing to click on Post Answer , i would simply not publish this answer but main point which  i pointed out the misconception about ifs and switch which make perfect sense in situations like OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at using a [switch (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) statement.

> The switch statement is a control statement that selects a switch
>   section to execute from a list of candidates.

Comment: +1.... or skip `switch` and go directly with `Dictionary<string, Action<string>>` map of `dropdown` to delegate that sets value you want.